# Using knitr with cluster computing

Tags: r, latex, cluster-computing, knitr

I have a R script which needs to be run repeatedly. (For concreteness, I am talking about 500-1000 independent computationally-intensive MCMC chains which I want to summarize in just a few key plots at the end.)  My school has a server available that uses a queuing system that makes these computations feasible.  Right now I submit multiple jobs to the "short" queue since it is less overburdened than the "multicore" or "long" job queues. I have been running it by having the R script called multiple times, so I am submitting 50 jobs of 10 chains apiece and saving the results to a single output file by appending.  This is my job submission code:

```
for ARRAYVAR in `seq 1 1 50`
    do
       bsub -q short -u me@school.edu R CMD BATCH "CODE.R --args arg1 = $ARRAYVAR"
    done
```

ARRAYVAR is used only for setting the random number seed.  Once the jobs have all completed, the plotting is then done in a separate script.

For homework assignments and previous research, I have used knitr with Rstudio to combine LaTeX notes with my R code. The end result is a single .Rnw that generates a reproducible document containing all notes, code, and results.  I liked that approach much better since I could always be sure the plots/results corresponded to the code version I saw in front of me.  Is it possible to do something similar here so that there is one file that I could re-run to reproduce my findings?  I am new to using the cluster and R without Rstudio.